# Query to check the most active editors over a specific period

Tags: support, edits, data-explorer, recent

Is there a way to do that without being limited by having to be the last editor of the specific posts, as seen with the use of `Posts.LastEditorUserId` in [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/189797/top-20-most-prolific-editors-for-a-specific-date-range).

As a bonus, is there some way to specify, say the last 30 days of activity, instead of having to specify **start** and **end** dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query should do the trick: [Top editors in the past n days](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/189839/). I'm not sure that this counts edits in the same way as the users tab does, though.

For SO, counting edits for the past 30 days, we have:

```
User Link        Count 
---------------- ----- 
Tshepang         3728  
Kara             3267  
marc_s           2410  
rmaddy           2393  
Roman C          1914  
Community        1630  
tereško          1041  
Martijn Pieters  900   
OneKitten        786   
Benjamin         772   
verdesrobert     751   
Soner Gönül      738   
Jason Aller      732   
Bob Malooga      640   
halfer           625   
simoco           623   
Larme            615   
Peter Mortensen  600   
Charles          567   
Jonathan Leffler 545
```

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230937