# Data Explorer query to count number of edits, but using the same criteria as the Users->editors tab

Tags: support, data-explorer

How does one create a query similar to the one seen on [the editors tab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=week)? [This one](https://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/189883) skews the count a bit: it counts title, body, and tag edits separately, even when they occur within the same grace period.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how that query is run exactly but I assume [Top Editors](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201413/top-editors?DaysBack=7) comes close.

The inner query first determines the distinct user and post in a 5 minute interval. Over that set we group by user and count the nbumber of records.

```
DECLARE @days_diff int = ##DaysBack:int?7##

select UserId as [User Link]
, Count(*) as [Count]
FROM(
SELECT 
  UserId,
  PostId,
  Count(*) as [PC]
FROM
  PostHistory
WHERE
PostHistoryTypeId IN (4,5,6) -- title, body , tags
  AND CreationDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -@days_diff, GETDATE())
GROUP BY
  UserId
  , PostId
  , (year(CreationDate) * 60 * 24 * 31 * 12 
  + datepart(mm, CreationDate) * 60 * 24 * 31
  + datepart(dd, CreationDate) * 60 * 24
  + datepart(hh, CreationDate) * 60
  + datepart(mi, CreationDate)) / 5
  ) as edits
group by UserId  
ORDER BY
  [Count] DESC
```

I did start off with [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/189839/top-editors-in-the-past-n-days) by user [Senshin](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/11293/senshin)

Comment: How would you go about making the number of users configurable? I get different results when I use `select top user_count` on the outer query.

Comment: Strange,it doesn't do anything different for me if add top. I added that and retested.

Comment: I think I saw what the issue is: if you tweak `top_users`, you will see the actual counts differ. For example, with **10**, JakeGould count is 468, but with **200**, it's 472. Curious.